# Source for Italy coming from a staff in the sea

Tags: sources-mekorot, beis-hamikdash, king-solomon, italy

I learned today that after Shlomo HaMelech's wedding with the Egyptian princess was held on Yom Kippur and he slept in late accidentally on the day the Beis HaMikdosh was going to be inaugurated, that Hashem had a malach place a staff in the sea that later collected so much mud and debris that it became Calabria. Can I have a source for this, please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sh'lomo married the daughter of Pharaoh just before building the Temple as we see in [I Kings 3:1](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt09a03.htm):

> וַיִּתְחַתֵּן שְׁלֹמֹה, אֶת-פַּרְעֹה מֶלֶךְ מִצְרָיִם; וַיִּקַּח אֶת-בַּת-פַּרְעֹה, וַיְבִיאֶהָ אֶל-עִיר דָּוִד, עַד כַּלֹּתוֹ לִבְנוֹת אֶת-בֵּיתוֹ וְאֶת-בֵּית יְהוָה, וְאֶת-חוֹמַת יְרוּשָׁלִַם סָבִיב
>
> And Solomon became allied to Pharaoh king of Egypt by marriage, and took Pharaoh's daughter, and brought her into the city of David, until he had made an end of building his own house, and the house of the LORD, and the wall of Jerusalem round about. (Trans. [JPS](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt09a03.htm))

The Gemara Shabbat 56b states:

> אמר רב יהודה אמר שמואל: בשעה שנשא שלמה את בת פרעה ירד גבריאל ונעץ קנה בים, ועלה בו שירטון, ועליו נבנה כרך גדול [של רומי]. במתניתא תנא: אותו היום שהכניס ירבעם שני עגלי זהב אחד בבית אל ואחד בדן נבנה צריף אחד, וזהו איטליאה של יון
>
> Rab Judah said in Samuel's name: When Solomon married Pharaoh's daughter, Gabriel descended and planted a reed in the sea, and it gathered a bank around it, on which the great city of Rome was built.  In a Baraitha it was taught: On the day that Jeroboam brought the two golden calves, one into Bethel and the other into Dan, a hut was built,  and this developed into Greek Italy. (Trans. from [here](http://www.come-and-hear.com/shabbath/shabbath_56.html)).

The Midrash Vayikra Rabba to Parshat Sh'mini (12:5) states that Solomon slept in when he married Pharaoh's daughter and inaugurated the Temple.

> א"ר יודן כל אותן שבע שנים שבנה שלמה בית המקדש לא שתה בהן יין, כיון שבנה בית המקדש ונשא את בת פרעה אותו הלילה שתה יין... ר' יצחק בן אלעזר אמ' שלש מאות מיני ריקודים ריקדה בת פרעה באותו הלילה. והיה שלמה ישן עד ארבע שעות ביום ומפתחות בית המקדש נתונין תחת ראשו.

R. Ovadiah of Bertinoro (Ta'anit 4:8) writes that the Temple was inaugurated on Yom Kippur. The Tosafot Yom Tov (there) explains how this is derived from the relevant verses and Midrashim:

> זה בנין בית המקדש - פירש הר"ב שנתחנך ביוה"כ. כלומר שגם יוה"כ היה בתוך ימי החנוך. כדמוכח במלכים א' סימן ח' ויעש את החג שבעת ימים ושבעת ימים. ומפורש בגמ' דמ"ק דף ט' דשבעת ימים היה החינוך קודם לשבעת ימי החג. ונמצא שבשבעה בתשרי שהם שני ימים קודם יוה"כ התחילו ימי החינוך.

So that covers every element of the story! (Except for the minor point that the angel planted a reed; not a staff).

Comment: This is also mentioned in Masheches Makkos

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the sleeping in late,this can be found in Bamidbar Rabbah 10:4.

Comment: If I could accept this answer also along with mevaqesh's I would. :) Thank you for the source.

Comment: B'midbar Rabba is around 600 years later than Vayikra Rabba, so most probably it is just quoting the Vayikra Rabba I already quoted.